ExpressJS autoreload with browsersync
Im trying to setup a simple express server with typescript, nodemon and browsersync.
I would like it to refresh the browser everytime a node file (ts file) is changed to reflect the changes in the browser.
This is my dev script:
"dev": "nodemon - exec 'ts-node' ./src/entry.ts",

and this is my simple app:
import express from 'express';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync'

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bs = browserSync.create();


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('');
});

bs.init({
    server: "./",
    middleware: [app]
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    return console.log(`Express server is listening at http://localhost:${port} `);
});

I can get the express server, and browser-sync ui working perfectly, though, when i change something in the express server, the browser is not reloading the page. I'm using url:
http://localhost:3001 to attatch the browser sync.
What Am I doing wrong? I have tried to access the url with port of 3001 instead of 3000, and setup nodemon to refresh and then browsersync in the terminal is refreshing too - but its not reloading the browser window.
nodemon.json
{
  "watch": [ "src" ],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/app.ts"
}

Complete package.json
{
  "name": "123",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon - exec 'ts-node' ./src/entry.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.2",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "globals": "^15.8.0"
  }
}


Very similar question here.

no, this question is not the same. this is about reloading a browser-tab, when code change (browser-sync)
